# Worker raising a static event so that consumers can subscribe to it without holding the same instance to the worker

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I have a non-static class which does something and when it finishes it, I want to raise an event in my system.

Is it OK if I do something like:

```
public class Worker
{
  public void DoWork()
  {
    SystemEvents.RaiseWorkDoneEvent(this, ...);
  }
}

public static class SystemEvents
{
  public delegate void WorkDoneEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
  public static event WorkDoneEventHandler WorkDoneEvent;

  public void RaiseWorkDoneEvent(...)
  {
    WorkDoneEvent(...)
  }
}

public class Consumer
{
  // subscribe to SystemEvents.WorkDoneEvent
  // This class has no instance (or not the same instance) of Worker when it fires the event.
}
```

I understand the event belongs to `Worker`, however, I won't have an instance of it in my `Consumer` when this event happens.

Is this approach OK?

Comment: I would use `EventHandler<T>` instead of creating my own delegate, like `public static event EventHandler<EventArgs> WorkDoneEvent;` and ensure you invoke the event thread-safely.  (i.e. copy the event delegate, then check for null). The assignment to the delegate is apparently thread-safe; often a concern with statics.

Comment: Where exactly do you subscribe to the event? Do you unsubscribe when you no longer want to receive it? The static event is going to keep whatever instances signed up to receive it alive, until they unsubscribe.

Comment: @mikez, I would subscribe to it in a WPF View Model, which will be alive for the duration of the application run. It is a single subscriber, a single instance. I have read some info about the concern you have just pointed out.

Comment: I see. Also that won't actually compile, SystemEvents is going to need some method that `Worker` calls to raise the event since events cannot be raised outside the class that declares them.

Comment: @mikez, I thought so. The provided code is just for illustrating purposes, but I will adjust it per your comment.

Comment: But the question is - is it generally OK to do it like this? The whole point of the thing is - I want consumers to receive events from a worker class, without holding the exact same instance of the class which is raising the event.

Comment: Right... This is certainly the simplest way to do it. This concern comes up often enough that there are well known patterns with names like Event Aggregator pattern to handle the decoupling of event source from recipient. You can implement those, but they will add some complexity to the overall solution.

Comment: Do not use a static class for SystemEvents. Build/use an event aggregator class and keep one instance in your application for the SystemEvents. Use a DI container to have a singleton **instance**

Comment: @SirRufo, could you structure that as an answer here?